# Getting overall accuracy of n different confusion matrices by averaging accuracy of all n confusion matrices

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I want to test the accuracy of a cforest classification model. I ran it 50 times, and I got a different classification for each run. I also have the ground truth, i.e., the real classification to test against.

For each classification I computed a confusion matrix (in total 50 confusion matrices). Can I now calculate the mean of all 50 accuracy values that I got from the individual confusion matrices in order to get an overall accuracy of my model? Would that be an accurate way to test the (average) accuracy of my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated that you ran the model (forest classification model) 50 times on the same dataset and each and every time you got different results, which is possible as the model used different `hyperparameter` values each time it ran, and as the name suggest it is a tree model so, the tree cuts would be different.

There are two solutions to it:

First approach, as you suggested to take average, and to be more specific as this is a classification model you can take the `majority vote` of the `confusion matrix` and then finalise your result. This will give you fairly accurate results.

Second approach , which is more logical is to set the `nfold cross validation` parameter in your model to be `50` or a similar parameter which retrains the model automatically 50 times using 50 different data cuts, then this will give you a single model and better performance over the 50 averaged model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As for the first solution, I'm fairly new to the topic, so to me it's not entirely clear how I calculate a majority vote of all 50 confusion matrices (or what that is exactly)? Could you maybe elaborate a bit more on that? The second approach I understand. - Just to be clear, it would not be a good idea in your opinion to simply average all 50 accuracy values in order to make an assumption about the average performance of my classification model?